# Embed iframe created in a js file in current web page when clicked on IE edge extension

Tags: javascript, content-script, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to create a IE edge extension where in I want to embed a iframe (created in javascript file) in current web page when clicked on extension icon. I know we need to make use of content scripts but unable to understand how to inject them in another js. I am new to extensions as well as js. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the documentation here regarding **tabs.executeScipt** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript). Using this API you will be able to inject JS into the content page (webpage). The same can be used to inject an IFRAME into the page.

Comment: Thanks!! This helped me find the solution